# Cast char to int by zero extending in C++

Tags: c++, casting, type-conversion, undefined-behavior, standards-compliance

I want to write a function

```
int char_to_int(char c);
```

that converts given char to int by zero extending the value. So if the char has N bits and int has M bits, M >= N, then the M-N most significant bits of the int value should be zero and the N least significant bits of the int value should match the bits of the char value.

This seems like a simple task, but I'm not sure how to write it relying only on standard behavior. No UB, no implementation-defined behavior. Without relying on char being 8 bit, int being 32 bit, char being unsigned and any other common assumptions I make that are not guaranteed by standard.

The reason I want to know this, is that I have done this conversion several times in the past, but recently I became aware about the limited guarantees C++ gives about it's data types. So now I'm curious what is the correct, standard compliant approach.

I don't suppose

```
return (int) c;
```

is good enough, is it?

Comment: Is `char` signed on your platform and do you really want to zero-fill if it is signed and has a negative value?

Comment: Yes, I want there to be zeros. Think of it like a bitfield. The numerical value is irrelevant.

Comment: Using `std::byte` (if C++ >= 17) for this sort of usage would be better, or one of the fixed-length ints (e.g. `uint8_t` if C++ >= 11)

Comment: @Novotny if you want a bitfield then why not use a [`bitset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset)?

Comment: This is a purely informative question. I know there are alternatives, but in the past I had to work with char (returned by a library) and had to convert it to int (required by a different function in the same library). Now I reminisce and want to know the correct strategy.

Answer (score 2):

There's no hurt in being extra clear:

```
return int((unsigned char)c);
```

That way you tell the compiler exactly what you want: the int that contains the char value, read as unsigned. So char 255 will become int 255.

Comment: Do note that `sizeof(int)` can equal `sizeof(char)` and in that case you'll get some implementation defined value.

Comment: @NathanOliver: The value may technically be "implementation-defined", but have there ever been any implementations where UCHAR_MAX exceeds INT_MAX that did not define unsigned-to-signed conversions such that `(unsigned)(int)(unsigned)(someValue)` wasn't equal to `(unsigned)(someValue)`?

Comment: I'll wait a while and if no one protests I will mark this as accepted. It's a lot simpler than I thought. I was expecting some kind of nested reinterpret_cast was needed.

Comment: Definitely not `reinterpret_cast`. Those can be statically cast. If you want to be explicit, you can write: `static_cast<int>(static_cast<unsigned char>(c))`. My understanding is that this is parsed exactly the same as the line above. But it feel a bit heavy.